# What is the most efficient way to compare multiple sets of data for overlaps in C#

Tags: c#, performance

I am wondering what is the most efficient way to find overlapping data in multiple sets with different number of records in C#?

Let's have this example:

```
Set1: +- 20 records       Set2: +- 50 records
 ID | Value                ID | Value
 1  | Value01               1 | ValueA
 2  | Value02               2 | ValueB
 3  | Value03               3 | Value01
 4  | Value04               4 | ValueD
 5  | Value05               5 | Value17
   ...                           ....
20  | Value20              50 | Value XY


Set3: +- 2 000 records    Set4: +- 3 000 records
 ID | Value               ID | Value
 1  | Random               1 | Dog
 2  | Random02             2 | Duck
 3  | Random03             3 | John
 4  | Random04             4 | Pen
 5  | Ranodm05             5 | Argument
   ...                           ....
```

The idea is to chceck, that each set contains only exclusive records. And if one record is present in more than one table, this record should be marked as overlapping.

Mathematically said:

∀A, B, C, D :  A ∩ (B ∪ C ∪ D) = {} ∧ B ∩ (C ∪ D) = {} ∧ C ∩ D = {}

What I am trying to achieve is create a function in C# that will take as input 4 sets and will return probably something like dictionary. Containing 3 dictionaries (set1 overlaps, set2 overlaps, set3 overlaps)

So output should look something like this:

```
var result = new Dictionary<SetsEnum, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<SetsEnum, int>>>
{
  { SetsEnum.Set1, 
    { 
      {<set1overlappingRowId1>,
        {
          { SetsEnum.<setX>, <overlappingRowIdX> },
          { SetsEnum.<setY>, <overlappingRowIdY> } 
        }
      },
      {<set1overlappingRowId2>,
        {
          { SetsEnum.<setZ>, <overlappingRowIdZ> }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope i did not make any mistake in brackets.
Basically it should says something like this:

Set1-Row5 overlaps with: Set2-Row42, Set3-Row1513
Set1-Row18 overlaps with: Set4-Row481
Set2-Row30 overlaps with: Set3-Row987
etc.

I hope it is clear enough.

Only approach I am able to think of id:

1. Order sets by size from smallest to largest
2. For each record in set 1 check for overlaps in sets 2, 3 and 4.
3. For each record in set 2 check for overlaps in sets 3 and 4.
4. For each record in set 3 check for overlaps in set 4.
5. Return dictionary of overlaps.

Does exist simplier solution for something like this in C#?

Ps. In fack I was wondering about one more solution. If any overlap is found, mark this record with flag and then work only with not overlapping records (this may speed things up a bit. But implementation of such functionality seems unnecessary complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a sort of inner join you can use this here as a starting point - be aware, that it generates a full outer join:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> GenerateMapping<TLeft, TRight, TResult>(IEnumerable<TLeft> leftList,
                                                                                IEnumerable<TRight> rightList,
                                                                                Func<TLeft, String> leftSortKey,
                                                                                Func<TRight, String> rightSortKey,
                                                                                Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> factory)
        where TLeft : class
        where TRight : class
    {
        var result = new List<TResult>();
        var sortedLeftList = leftList.OrderBy(leftSortKey, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray();
        var sortedRightList = rightList.OrderBy(rightSortKey, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray();

        var left = 0;
        var right = 0;
        var total = sortedLeftList.Length + sortedRightList.Length;

        while (left + right < total)
        {
            if (left < sortedLeftList.Length && right < sortedRightList.Length)
            {
                var compare = String.Compare(
                    leftSortKey(sortedLeftList[left]),
                    rightSortKey(sortedRightList[right]),
                    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

                if (compare < 0)
                {
                    result.Add(factory(sortedLeftList[left], null));
                    left++;
                }
                if (compare > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(factory(null, sortedRightList[right]));
                    right++;
                }
                if (compare == 0)
                {
                    result.Add(factory(sortedLeftList[left], sortedRightList[right]));
                    left++;
                    right++;
                }
            }
            else if (left < sortedLeftList.Length)
            {
                result.Add(factory(sortedLeftList[left], null));
                left++;
            }
            else if (right < sortedRightList.Length)
            {
                result.Add(factory(null, sortedRightList[right]));
                right++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Possibly some implementations with Lookups will perform faster.
You can find them with searching for [inner|left|right|full] join and LinQ

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate all sets into one set and then order by Value or group by Value, you can easily count how many times each Value appears. You will need to keep track of which set each item originates from.
In this example I used 3 small sets and simple ints and strings, but the idea should be clear.

```
struct MyData
{
    public int SetID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("SetID={0}, ID={1}, Value={2}", SetID, ID, Value);
    }
}
```

and then the search itself:

```
var set1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var set2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var set3 = new Dictionary<int, string>();

set1.Add(1, "Value01");
set1.Add(2, "Value02");
set1.Add(3, "Value03");
set1.Add(4, "Value04");
set1.Add(5, "Value05");
set1.Add(6, "Value06");
set1.Add(7, "Value07");
set1.Add(8, "Value08");
set1.Add(9, "Value09");
set1.Add(10, "Value10");

set2.Add(1, "ValueA");
set2.Add(2, "ValueB");
set2.Add(3, "Value01");
set2.Add(4, "ValueD");
set2.Add(5, "Value17");
set2.Add(6, "ValueX");
set2.Add(7, "ValueY");
set2.Add(8, "ValueZ");
set2.Add(9, "Value16");

set3.Add(1, "ValueT");
set3.Add(2, "Random");
set3.Add(3, "Duck");
set3.Add(4, "Arg");
set3.Add(5, "Value03");
set3.Add(6, "Value01");
set3.Add(7, "ValueD");
set3.Add(8, "ValueB");
set3.Add(9, "Whatever");

var search = set1.Select(kvp => new MyData { SetID = 1, ID = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value })
    .Concat(set2.Select(kvp => new MyData { SetID = 2, ID = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value })
).Concat(set3.Select(kvp => new MyData { SetID = 3, ID = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value })
).GroupBy(md => md.Value);

var unique = new HashSet<MyData>();
var dupes = new HashSet<MyData>();
foreach (var grp in search) {
    if (grp.Take(2).Count() > 1) {
        foreach (var data in grp) dupes.Add(data);
    } else {
        unique.Add(grp.Single());
    }
}
foreach (var data in unique) Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (var data in dupes) Console.WriteLine(data);
```

dupes will contain:

```
SetID=1, ID=1, Value=Value01
SetID=2, ID=3, Value=Value01
SetID=3, ID=6, Value=Value01
SetID=1, ID=3, Value=Value03
SetID=3, ID=5, Value=Value03
SetID=2, ID=2, Value=ValueB
SetID=3, ID=8, Value=ValueB
SetID=2, ID=4, Value=ValueD
SetID=3, ID=7, Value=ValueD
```